# Want to send the status of the build to bitbucket server from Azure Devops build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure DevOps build pipeline and want to send the build status to bitbucket code repository.
I need to check these build status before merging the feature/bugfix branch to develop branch.

Is there a clean way to integrate this in the DevOps Project?

Comment: Hi Tejas, any update for this issue. Please check Sajeetharan's answer helps to resolve your ssue, just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with a simple [`script`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/integrate-your-build-system-with-bitbucket-cloud-790790968.html) in your pipeline and update with the build id

```
script: |
  import os
  id = os.getenv('BUILD_BUILDID')
  print(id)
```